# How do I fix " NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken @ngrx/router-store Configuration!" after upgrading to ngrx v8 on my Angular project?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I just upgraded a project from Angular 6 (and ngrx 6) to Angular 8.  I tried to follow the migration guide for Angular 8, and was able to get everything to build, but ended up getting this error when I run it:

Full error message:

```js
Unhandled Promise rejection: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[StoreRouterConnectingModule -> InjectionToken @ngrx/router-store Configuration]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[StoreRouterConnectingModule -> InjectionToken @ngrx/router-store Configuration]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken @ngrx/router-store Configuration! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[StoreRouterConnectingModule -> InjectionToken @ngrx/router-store Configuration]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[StoreRouterConnectingModule -> InjectionToken @ngrx/router-store Configuration]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken @ngrx/router-store Configuration!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44694:25)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44932:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44876:16)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44780:20)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44932:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44876:16)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44780:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:61915:29)
    at _createClass (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:61968:32)
    at _createProviderInstance (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:61932:26) NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[StoreRouterConnectingModule -> InjectionToken @ngrx/router-store Configuration]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[StoreRouterConnectingModule -> InjectionToken @ngrx/router-store Configuration]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken @ngrx/router-store Configuration!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44694:25)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44932:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44876:16)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44780:20)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44932:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44876:16)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44780:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:61915:29)
    at _createClass (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:61968:32)
    at _createProviderInstance (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:61932:26)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After a bit of Googling (without finding the direct answer) I re-read the ngrx [upgrade guide](https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v8#ngrxrouter-store), and it had this nugget:

> Usage of forRoot is now required for StoreRouterConnectingModule

BEFORE:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreRouterConnectingModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

AFTER

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot() // <-- gotta do this
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I fixed this in my AppModule, and that did the trick!

Note to self: next time read all the parts of the migration guide.

Comment: How did you upgrade? Normally if you would use `ng update @ngrx/store`, it should have made these changes for you :)

Comment: @timdeschryver thanks for the tip.  I'm sure I did it wrong, but your comment will hopefully help someone else :)

Comment: Thanks for saving me hour of debugging, before heading to the docs :D.

Comment: Saved a ton of time !